# list to matrix conversion with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

Starting from a list of floats, i.e.

```
register = [11, 12, 13, 23, 24, 34]
```

I would like to generate symmetric matrices where elements of the diagonal equal to zero, i.e.

```
[[  0.  11.  12.  13.]
 [ 11.   0.  23.  24.]
 [ 12.  23.   0.  34.]
 [ 13.  24.  34.   0.]]
```

So I opted for creating a zero with dimension 4 x 4 then to be filled with the elements of my list.  After setting a progress indicator and considering an offset to not overwrite the zeroes of the diagonal, I then would either move to east (or south) until the number of previously determined steps to reach the limit of the matrix were consumed.  After incrementing of the progress and reset of the initial step counter, I could enter the next column (line) to proceed further.  However, I erred in my present code (at least once -- it is my first contact with numpy) and harvest only

```
[[  0.  11.  12.  13.]
 [ 11.   0.  23.   0.]
 [ 12.  23.   0.   0.]
 [ 13.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

My code:

```
 import numpy as np
 dimension = 4    # other matrices' dimensions will be larger
 matrix = np.zeros((dimension,dimension))

 register = [11, 12, 13, 23, 24, 34]

 progress = 0
 inner_step = 0
 i = 0

 for progress in range(0, (dimension + 1)):
 permitted_steps = dimension - progress
 for i in range(progress, permitted_steps-1):
     matrix[(progress, inner_step+1+offset)] = register[0]
     matrix[(inner_step+1+offset, progress)] = register[0]
     inner_step += 1
     del register[0]

 progress += 1
 inner_step = 0
 offset += 1
```

The targeted environment used is Python 2.7 (Continuum Anaconda) for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close, your issue occurs when `progress` is equal to or greater than `permitted_steps-1` as there is no range there to iterate through. try this:

```
    import numpy as np

    dimension = 4
    matrix = np.zeros((dimension,dimension))

    register = [11, 12, 13, 23, 24, 34]
    progress = 0
    inner_step = 0
    i = 0
    offset = 0
    for progress in range(0, (dimension + 1)):
        permitted_steps = dimension - progress
        for i in range(0, permitted_steps-1):
            matrix[(progress, inner_step+1+offset)] = register[0]
            matrix[(inner_step+1+offset, progress)] = register[0]
            inner_step += 1
            del register[0]
        progress += 1
        inner_step = 0
        offset +=1
    print matrix
```

And that will print out:

```
[[  0.  11.  12.  13.]
 [ 11.   0.  23.  24.]
 [ 12.  23.   0.  34.]
 [ 13.  24.  34.   0.]]
```

if you change your register array to length 10:

```
register = [11, 12, 13, 23, 24, 34, 37, 39, 40, 43]
```

you will get:

```
[[  0.  11.  12.  13.  23.]
 [ 11.   0.  24.  34.  37.]
 [ 12.  24.   0.  39.  40.]
 [ 13.  34.  39.   0.  43.]
 [ 23.  37.  40.  43.   0.]]
```

Comment: Considering myself pretty much as a beginner about Python, I really like this answer because it showed that there was little in addition to consider to perform the task successfully.   Even if the other answers are more condensed because they use functions in numpy (and scipy) I wasn't yet aware.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one vectorized approach leveraging `broadcasting` and `masking/boolean-indexing` -

```
r = np.arange(dimension)
mask = r[:,None] < r # Or in one step : ~np.tri(dimension,dtype=bool)
matrix[mask] = register
matrix.T[mask] = register
```

If you need to compute `dimension` from the given `register`, we could use :

```
dimension = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(2*len(register))))
```

And to assert for length, given `dimension`, we could have :

```
assert dimension*(dimension-1)//2 == len(register)
```

Also, for performance do consider feeding in the array version of `register`.

Sample run -

```
In [43]: import numpy as np
    ...: dimension = 4    # other matrices' dimensions will be larger
    ...: matrix = np.zeros((dimension,dimension))
    ...: 
    ...: register = [11, 12, 13, 23, 24, 34]

In [44]: r = np.arange(dimension)
    ...: mask = r[:,None] < r
    ...: matrix[mask] = register
    ...: matrix.T[mask] = register

In [45]: matrix
Out[45]: 
array([[ 0., 11., 12., 13.],
       [11.,  0., 23., 24.],
       [12., 23.,  0., 34.],
       [13., 24., 34.,  0.]])
```

**How `masking` could be better than generating all triangular indices**

Generating the indices would occupy more memory than creating a boolean array which by its very nature would be memory efficient and hence translates to better performance, especially on large arrays. Timings on this would try to prove it -

```
In [3]: import numpy as np
   ...: dimension = 5000    # other matrices' dimensions will be larger
   ...: register = np.random.randint(0,10,dimension*(dimension-1)//2)

# With masking and boolean-indexing
In [4]: %%timeit
   ...: matrix = np.zeros((dimension,dimension),dtype=int)
   ...: r = np.arange(dimension)
   ...: mask = r[:,None] < r
   ...: matrix[mask] = register
   ...: matrix.T[mask] = register
10 loops, best of 3: 108 ms per loop

# With triangular indices indexing
In [5]: %%timeit
   ...: N = dimension
   ...: matrix = np.zeros((dimension,dimension),dtype=int)
   ...: idx = np.triu_indices(N, k=1)
   ...: matrix = np.zeros((N, N))
   ...: matrix[idx] = register
   ...: matrix.T[idx] = register
1 loop, best of 3: 364 ms per loop
```

Comment: Is there any advantage of this over `np.triu_indices()`?

Comment: @norok2 Good question. Added section at the end including timings.

Comment: For just starting to work with numpy, this was very much more than anticipated -- and in much more depth, than expected.  Although the matrices to built are less large (up to about 80..100 columns/lines) delegating this work to Python clearly showed to be a huge time saver compared to manual rectangular mark and yank across Emacs' buffers and transpose paste in gnumeric...

Answer (score 5):

Just call [`scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html):

```
>>> import scipy.spatial.distance
>>> scipy.spatial.distance.squareform([11, 12, 13, 23, 24, 34])
array([[ 0, 11, 12, 13],
       [11,  0, 23, 24],
       [12, 23,  0, 34],
       [13, 24, 34,  0]])
```

The conversion you want is the same as the conversion from a condensed distance matrix to a square-form distance matrix, and `scipy.spatial.distance.squareform` performs that conversion (and its inverse). Be careful about dtypes, though; `[11, 12, 13, 23, 24, 34]` is a list of ints, not floats, and passing it to `squareform` will give you an array of ints. You can convert the input to floats or call `result.astype(float)` if you want floats.

Comment: Selecting integers instead of true floating numbers in the question aimed for useful simplification of the problem faced.  But I agree with you, I shall discern them more clearly, especially around Python and future use of numpy and eventually scipy.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another vectorised approach with `triu_indices`:

```
N = 4
idx = np.triu_indices(N, k=1)
matrix = np.zeros((N, N))
matrix[idx] = register
matrix.T[idx] = register
```

Generate a indices for the upper triangular matrix with a diagonal offset of 1, and then assign accordingly.

Ensure that register has enough elements to do this operation. You can enforce a precondition check using

```
assert len(register) == np.count_nonzero(1 - np.tri(N))
```

Comment: Condensed to the point (in sight of posts like (https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/115967/during-peer-review-should-i-comment-on-the-authors-messy-code)) plus a useful checkpoint in the code. Sadly, there is only once the mark of accepted answer.